# Detecting strong currents in a sparse directed graph

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, graph-theory, dag

I have a very large, sparse, weighted, directed graph. The structure is such that it mainly consists of strings of nodes connected with highly weighted edges. These strings can be connected by weak edges or fully unconnected.

- Is there an algorithm that will detect these highways / currents / linear clusters and group the nodes together?
- Otherwise, does this type of graph structure have a specific name that will help me research it more?

Comment: Have you looked at Max Flow algorithms?

Comment: I haven't, no. Am I right in that you have to know the source and sink in advance, for this type of algorithms? In that case it is not viable as this is not known a priori

Comment: Well, there are also multi-source multi-sink maximum flow problems. You'll need to look up the literature yourself, I havn't used any of them. Either way, flow algorithms seems to be the thing you need, not clustering or learning.

Answer (score 1):

[Maximum Flow Gephi tool](https://github.com/m1ci/Ford-Fulkerson-Gephi-tool)

Maybe this will help you to find a few more details for your problem. It is a Gephi tool based on the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.